# Need help solving a wind power problem involving wind speed, energy production, and optimization

Tags: integration, optimization

I am working on a wind power problem and need some help. Here is the problem:

During a windy day, the wind speed at a wind turbine can be described by the model:
$$
v(x)= 11 \sin(0.11x - 0.89) + 28, \qquad 0 \leq x \leq 24,
$$
where $v$ is the wind speed in km/h and $x$ is the time in hours from midnight.

(a) I need to find the maximum wind speed during the day.

(b) I also need to determine how long the wind speed is over 36 km/h during the day.

(c) Finally, I need to find the total amount of electrical energy that the wind turbine produces during the day.

My work is...

(a) I have attempted to solve this problem by finding the derivative of the function and setting it equal to zero to find the maximum wind speed. However, I am not sure if this is the correct approach.

(b) I have tried integrating the function over the range where the wind speed is greater than 36 km/h, but I am unsure if this is correct.

(c) I am planning to use the provided equation $P(v)= 0.42v^3$ to calculate the electrical energy produced and then integrate over the range of wind speeds.

I would appreciate any guidance on how to approach this problem and any corrections or improvements to my current attempts.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: In your formula $11\sin(0,11x−0,89)+28,$ is the number $0,11x−0,89$ in radians as usual, or in degrees? If it is in radians, the max of $v(x)$ is $11+28=39$ (attained for $x=\frac{0,89+\pi/2}{0,11}\approx22,37$).

Comment: Isn't it strange that $v(0)\ne v(24)?$

Comment: Note that in my first comment (solution for a), there was no need to take the derivative. Simply use that the max for $\sin$ is $\sin(\pi/2)=1.$

Comment: For b), integrating is not the right way. Solve $\sin(0,11x-0,89)>(36-28)/11,$ i.e. (approximately, and for $0\le x\le24$) $0,11x-0,89>0,814$ i.e. $15,49<x\le24.$

Answer (score 0):

(a) You are correct. You could take the derivative and set this derivative to 0. Find the $x$ in the interval $[0, 24]$ would find you *potential* values where the function was a maximum or minimum. However, be sure to use a derivative test to check which (if any) these values are! Because you are optimizing on the interval $[0, 24]$, you will also want to check the end-points $0$ and $24$ to see if these are maxima/minima on this interval!

(b) You want to find when $11 \sin(0.11x - 0.80) + 28 \geq 36$.You can simply solve for $\sin$ to obtain $\sin(0.11x - 80) \geq 0.72727\ldots$ (or better yet, $\sin(0.11x - 80) \geq \frac{8}{11}$). Using what you know about $\sin x$, you should be able to find the $x$ on the interval $[0, 24]$ that make this true. Perhaps, you are meant to do it graphically. However, you can use $\sin^{-1}$ to find the general solution(s), restrict to the interval $[0, 24]$, then use $0.11x - 80= \text{solution(s)}$ to solve for $x$ and then just take those in the interval $[0, 24]$. There are other approaches as well, depending on what you know or find easiest.

(c) My Physics is rusty and I am unsure if this is arising from a Science or Math class - which will matter to the 'realism' of the problem. The function $P(v)$ suggests to me a potential, but integrating this would give work. Would this then be work done by the wind, i.e. energy produced? I doubt this would have the correct units. Examining a some data, [for example from this site](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/emsc297/node/649) would seem to suggest that the energy produced over time is the velocity of the turbine times the time it runs at that velocity. So for a small moment in time, this would be $v(x) \Delta x$, and so to find the total energy one would take the limit resulting in the integral $\int_0^{24} x v(x) \;dx$. But then runs into the issue of why $P(v)$ is provided at all - with intuition telling you that they probably do want (as you suggest) $\int_0^{24} P(v) \;dx$, where you need substitute $P(v)= 0.42v^3= 0.42 (11 \sin(0.11x - 0.89) + 28)^3$. I hesitate to give an uniformed answer and so this is more a comment and perhaps someone better attuned with the Physics will be able to give better advice here.

Comment: For (c): Yes, the units are incorrect, but that's true already for the relation between time $x$ and velocity $v$. In ideal conditions, the power generated by a wind turbine is proportional to the cube of the wind speed (up to a certain wind speed), so the formula for power $P$ makes sense in that regard. So you need to integrate $P(x)=P(v(x))$ over one day to get the produced energy.